# How to append a variable to the same line as text

Tags: jquery, html

We want to add a counter after each append, but it's being put on separate lines.

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>Champlain</li>",(counter));


  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this way, `$("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>."+counter);`

Answer (score 0):

`$("ul").append("<li>Champlain" + counter.toString() + "</li>");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>Champlain " + counter++ + "</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul").append("<li>Champlain " + (counter++) + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an `<li>`, then more text.  `<li>` is a block element and will always be a separate horizontal block from whatever's before or after it.  (Barring CSS that states otherwise.)

Put the counter inside the element instead.

```
$("ul").append($("<li>").append("Champlain" + String(counter)));
```

I'm also a fan of not building HTML out of strings unless absolutely necessary.  :)